# Which dependencies can be injected through action methods in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I wondered how I could get the form data from a cshtml to the controller.
I tried `HttpContext.Request.Form.Data` and this didn't work.
By accident I found a question on SO where someone used:

```
public IActionResult Validate(IFormCollection form)
```

This worked.
Now I wonder how I can look up what other dependencies can be injected this way. Either by looking up the debugger, documentation or the source code. So in the future I know where to search.

Comment: Are you referring to ASP.NET (classic) MVC/Web API, or to ASP.NET Core?

Comment: In my case I'm using ASP.NET Core right now

Comment: I updated the title and tags of your question to reflect this.

Comment: By default, you can get the form data by using `HttpContext.Request.Form`, it contains key and value. And it is almost same with `IFormCollection`. Do not know how is your frontend code, model binding bind the data by name and actually add the simple type or complex model as parameter can receive the form data successfully.

Comment: The special behaviour of the IFormCollection parameter in this case is actually not based on Dependency Injection but on special handling of this type during "model binding" in the MVC framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any method which is called during startup may be adding many services to the DI container so it would be hard to document such a thing.

The easiest way, like you said is to use the debugger.

In .NET 5, you could hit a break-point in the ConfigureServices Method (in Startup.cs) and inspect the "services" argument as below. Expanding Results View will show many, (as you can see there are now 274, but before the call to `AddRazorPages`, there was less than 100.

[image]

For .NET6, you can just hit a break-point in Program.cs and inspect `Builder.Services` as shown below

[image]